# Use FFMPEG to create video from jpeg, and index using vlc

Tags: ffmpeg, encode, vlc, mpeg

OpenSuse 11.4
FFMEG 0.8.5

I'm using FFMPEG to create a 5 minute mpeg from about 2100 individual jpegs (7fps).  I've been using the following command (OpenSuse 11.4)
**/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -r 7.01 -i %03d-capture.jpg -s 800x600 -r 25 Event-3692-r1-s1-3.mpg**

Now I Try to open the file (In windows XP with VLC 1.1.11 Player).
Media->AdvancedFileOpen
*I select "Show more options" and set StartTime to 5s.  I expect that the video should start 5 seconds in, but instead it starts at a seemingling random (although consistent) time of ~30 seconds in.

I also tried changing ffmpeg command to:
**/usr/bin/ffmpeg -sameq -y -r 7.01 -i %03d-capture.jpg -s 800x600 -r 25 Event-3692-r1-s1-3.mpg**
*This result in about a constant 2x offset (5sec => 10sec) (10s => 20s) etc.  But filesize is also about 6x larger, which is a strain on my storage.

I also tried
**/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -r 7.01 -i %03d-capture.jpg -s 800x600 -r 25 -f mpegts Event-3692-r1-s1-3.mpg**
*This result in vlc not indexing at all into my video.  Also not desired.  Anybody have any clues what is going on here.  It is very important for me to be able to use this VLC feature and have it work correctly.

Thanks in advance